# instance_variable_set/get vs attr_writer/reader

Tags: ruby, instance-variables, accessor

Are there any situations where I should chose between `instance_varaible_set`/`instance_variable_get` or `attr_writer`/`attr_reader` to access an instance variable of the object from outside of it? How are they different in terms of speed, or etc?

I had the impression that if you want to let accessing the instance variable an opened method to the end user, `attr_writer`/`attr_reader` should be used to make it easy, but if you want to use it privately, you would rather use `instance_varaible_set`/`instance_variable_get`. Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is correct. You define `attr_accessor`/`attr_reader`/`attr_writer` inside class definition to make them access (implicitly or explicitly created) instance variable.

If class wasn't written by you and no such accessors exist, you still can read/write private instance variables using `instance_variable_get`/`instance_variable_set`.

Comment: I actually run a profiler, and it seems that instance_varaible_set/instance_variable_get are slightly slower.